# How to Copy multiple text line in clipboard and paste in another non java form

Tags: java, swing, clipboard, awtrobot

I want to copy multiple text line in **System clipboard** and paste them row by row into another application.

**Example to copy:**

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

**Paste:**
`a`, `b`, `c`, ...

I then want to paste it in another non java program (this program contains a text box into which I want to paste the text.). It should still be in the same format even after pasting. After each paste, it should automatically press <kbd>tab</kbd> and move the focus to another text box. Rinse and repeat for 2 more rows of text.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        Robot r = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    String toClipBoardText = jTextField1.getText()+"\n"+jTextField2.getText()+"\n"+jTextField3.getText()+"\n"+jTextField4.getText()+"\n"+jTextField5.getText();
    StringSelection stringClip = new StringSelection(toClipBoardText);
    clip.setContents(stringClip, stringClip);
}
```

Comment: This makes little sense to me. You want to paste it to a **non-java** application? Yet you want to paste it to a `JTextField`? You know that a `JTextField` is a class in **Java**, right? No other programming language has a class called `JTextField`.

Comment: i didn't write anywhere that paste in another form Jtextfield . i want to paste in textbox which is similer to java text box.

Comment: Yes you did! DevilsHnd was so kind and edited your question, but you originally talked about posting into a `JTextField`. Look up the edit history

Comment: here i want to get  solution for this query. It doesn't matter Jtextfield and textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a `Scanner` to traverse through the lines of code. Then we set the next line to the clipboard and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste the data using the `Robot` class. After clicking your `JButton` you have 5 seconds to click into the wanted text box. It will then start pasting and tabbing.

There are some `sleep(...)` statements in there because I don't know the UI you are working with it better save than sorry and give it some time to react.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;

// ...

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        String multiLineText = jTextField1.getText()+"\n"+jTextField2.getText()+"\n"+jTextField3.getText()+"\n"+jTextField4.getText()+"\n"+jTextField5.getText();
        Scanner textReader = new Scanner(multiLineText);
        Robot r = new Robot();

        System.out.println("You have 5 seconds to focus the text box into which the text will be pasted!");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(5 - i + "...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        System.out.println("Start pasting...");
        while (textReader.hasNext()) {
            String line = textReader.nextLine().trim();
            System.out.println("\t> Pasting \"" + line + "\"");

            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                    .getSystemClipboard()
                    .setContents(
                            new StringSelection(line),
                            null);

            pressKeys(r, VK_CONTROL, VK_V);
            pressKeys(r, VK_TAB);
        }

    } catch (AWTException | InterruptedException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

public static void pressKeys(Robot robot, int... keys) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        robot.keyPress(keys[i]);
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        robot.keyRelease(keys[keys.length - i - 1]);
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: if you have a `List<JTextField> textFields`, consider using `String multiLineText = textFields.stream().map(JTextField::getText).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));`. This solution works independently of how many `JTextField` you are using (you need java 8 though)

Comment: also consider upvoting and accepting this solution if it helped

Comment: Thankyou So much Lonely Neuron. It really works in my project........10 out of 10 from my side.........

Comment: @aditya you are welcome. Please consider also upvoting the answer

Comment: can you give answer this query? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49964929/search-data-in-excel-using-java-program