# Search data in excel using Java program

Tags: java, database, swing, awt

I want to search data in excel sheet by using Java program.
Condition:

1. Write search data in text field and press Jbutton for search.
2. Textfield data goes to excel file and find row who contain matching data.
3. Row data copy and move to java program and Copy in 1 and more Textfield.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What did you try so far? I don't see research on your part

Comment: @[aditya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9675389/aditya) of course I read it. But this is no question! Provide any code or additional information and phrase a valid question...

Comment: @aditya - This appears to be nothing more than a request for someone to write you (or find you) some code.  StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service.  If you want someone to write code for you, Google can find you "rent a coder" sites where you can hire someone to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You better use macros to achieve this functionality.